# PlayN - ArrayBufferView size is not a small enough positive integer

Tags: playn

I have a very simple TicTacToe game using PlayN and Tomcat that works fine in Java. However, the html version on Chrome keeps getting:

[FATAL] Uncaught JavaScript exception [Uncaught RangeError: ArrayBufferView size is not a small enough positive integer.]

as soon as the server writes some stuff on the socket.

On Firefox, the exception is:

[FATAL] Uncaught JavaScript exception [Error: invalid arguments] in...

How can a buffer be "not small enough"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a likely explanation of the error:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129854

It sounds like a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays) is being initialized incorrectly. Usually, when I've encountered problems like this, it's been something that Google Web Toolkit has compiled in an faulty or unexpected way.

Track down that array in your Java code and try giving it a different parameter or perhaps changing the datatype you're using.

Hope that helps.